# AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_agraph'?

Tags: python

I'm data analysis using  GoaTools, I installed all the sufficient packages, its shows error. Not able to figure it out. Help is needed.
Using Python 3.7.6

```
python plot_go_term.py --term=GO:0005737 --gml 
go-basic.obo: fmt(1.2) rel(2020-06-01) 47,233 GO Terms
GO:0005737  level-02    depth-02    cytoplasm [cellular_component]
all parents: {'GO:0005575', 'GO:0110165'}
all children: {'GO:0016528', 'GO:0099631', 'GO:0106037', 'GO:0045495', 'GO:0060293', 'GO:0032838', 'GO:0120111', 'GO:0097575', 'GO:1902716', 'GO:0061846', 'GO:1990753', 'GO:1904115', 'GO:0099568', 'GO:0051285', 'GO:0097014', 'GO:0098831', 'GO:0032839', 'GO:0099738', 'GO:0045179', 'GO:0061803', 'GO:0061802', 'GO:0045180', 'GO:1990917', 'GO:0005938', 'GO:0031097', 'GO:0098834', 'GO:1904269'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_go_term.py", line 59, in <module>
    draw_children=opts.draw_children)
  File "/home/cent/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/goatools/obo_parser.py", line 594, in draw_lineage
    obj = nx.from_agraph(grph) if engine == "pygraphviz" else nx.from_pydot(grph)
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'from_agraph'
```

Comment: Please show us a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: It looks like `nx.from_agraph` is from an older version of the library. Newer versions do have `nx.nx_agraph.from_agraph`. You are possibly using a tutorial which targets an older version. I haven't used the library, so I might have missed something.

Comment: I'm using networkx 2.4.

Comment: What version is GoaTools using? When I did a google search on `networkx .from_agraph` the only thing I found for documentation is for version 1.11 (or older), where the website has the warning "This documents an unmaintained version of NetworkX. Please upgrade to a maintained version"

Comment: I'm using 3.7 GoaTools & networkx - 2.4.